# Cypress isn't retaining my authentication cookie when using visit() multiple times in one test

Tags: cypress

Part of my Cypress E2E tests are validating that certain URLs are fully restricted so users without the correct role cannot access them. To that end, I've written a scenario with multiple visit statements in it:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit(Cypress.env(HOST_URL));
   
});


it('cannot scan without scan role', () => {
    cy.login(standard.userName, password);
    cy.get('#scanDirectoryLink_text')
        .should('not.exist');
    cy.visit(`${Cypress.env(HOST_URL)}/scanning`);
    cy.url()
        .should('not.include', 'scanning')
        .should('not.include', 'login');
});
```

In this scenario, I both validate that the link to the page is not visible, and that directly navigating to the URL won't succeed. My problem is that when I use the second cy.visit() command, it bumps me back to the login page. So technically it doesn't reach the page, but the reason for this is not what I intended.

I don't want to preserve my cookies between tests, but I'm hoping to preserve them across multiple cy.visit() calls so that I don't loose my authentication. Or else is there a better way to programmatically move to a new URL within my site?

Answer (score -3):

Try add this in support/index.js

```
Cypress.LocalStorage.clear = function (keys, ls, rs) {
  //keep localStorage
  return;
}
```

Comment: my token is not stored in localStorage, it's in a cookie.